# Using image container for development

Tags: xcode, visual-studio, project-organization

We are a mid sized company and create a game engine by using C++ for all major operating systems (macOS, Windows and Linux). One issue we are facing is the amount of different configurations on developer machines. Some use different versions of Visual Studio, Xcode or other development tools. We have guide lines and a list with version numbers we officially use but at the end of the day we end up with these different configurations on everyones machine because everyone installs what they want.

Does anyone have experience with this problem, and how did you solve this? We often run into scenarios with "But it works on my machine".

I am eyeballing on (docker) containers to ensure everybody uses the same development environment, but I have my doubts its the right way to go for a C++ real time project. Any hints?

*Disclaimer: I was wondering if SO is the right place to ask this question, according to MetaExchange, it is*